# Movie (pre-1998) - Alien like creatures on an abandoned airport

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror, b-movies

I saw this movie when I was a very young kid with my grandpa circa 1995-1997. I don't remember when the movie was actually produced, but I have a feeling it wasn't a very old movie, like pre 1990s, or an 80s, 70s movie. It should have been made around 1990-1996. I remember the graphics of the aliens were good at the time (although if I saw them now they would probably look cartoon-ish). My guess is it a b-movie horror flick (most likely with bad ratings).

It was an adult movie (but he didn't care). It was certainly very frightening to me at the time and there was a lot of blood and even aliens eating people (I don't remember many more details though). I was glued to the screen. I remember there were rounded-shape aliens, or strange looking red demon like creatures that appeared not to just haunt but actually attack a group of people that were stranded in an abandoned airport. It's not much of a thriller movie, but horror & science fiction I believe, with a touch of mystery before the aliens made their full on appearance and were trying to eat everyone. By the way it was an American movie, everyone was speaking English.

I can't remember how this group of people got themselves there, their airplane crashed (but how would they survive then?) or something else happened. But I do remember it was an abandoned airport for sure. They found themselves stranded there and there was NOBODY there. They tried to call for help but all communications were down (not 100% sure on this). It was a wide open desert-like field (looked like Arizona or Colorado). I don't remember any of the actors either, but a white male protagonist on the role and a white female as well as a few other people in the group of various colors etc. It had a mystery feel on the first half of the movie and the other half was horror. I don't remember what happens in the end either. I do sort of remember they reach the conclusion that the aliens ate everyone there though.

I remember that those were in fact aliens and not demons. The movie was clinging on Sci-Fi not paranormal (that's why I don't think they were demons). Pretty sure on the alien part.

I have a clue as to how the group found themselves there. I believe it is correct. Their airplane needed emergency refueling, so by radar the pilot found a nearby airport (but I don't believe he communicated with someone). So they decided to make an emergency landing and upon arrival they could not find ANYONE there. So they were looking around, the passengers were curious. All in all the group of people couldn't have been more than 20. I remember the airplane that got them there was quite big but that doesn't justify the fact that the people were few in numbers.

Comment: You don't need to include "update" or "edit" in posts, we can tell from the revision history

Comment: I know it is not the movie due to timing, etc., but I am amazed by the similar plot.  The movie Pitch Black has a big ship with a lot of people crash but a mixed group survives.  They land on a planet and find an outpost devoid of life.  It is not till part way through the movie that they discover it is inhabited by creatures that eat everything, including each other.  Not the answer, just striking similarities.

Comment: @Jammin4CO Please check [our policy on duplication of story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sorry, I don't know how to message you directly.  Thank you for the clarification.  It took a while to understand why the community accepts the practice.  I now understand this question is not deleted, it is just considered answered somewhere else.  I looked in the help files for this answer and didn't think to scour the meta posts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Feels like [The Langoliers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/?ref_=nv_sr_1) from a Stephen King Book

> On a red eye flight to Boston from LA 10 people wake up to a shock.
>   All the passengers and crew have vanished. When they try to contact
>   the ground they make no connections. They land the plane only to
>   discover that things haven't changed. But its like the world is dead.
>   No one is there, the air is still, sound doesn't echo, the food is
>   tasteless. And a distant sound is heard coming closer. A race of
>   monstrous beings bent on their destruction is heading for them, eating
>   everything in sight.

[image: Round 'Aliens']

Comment: Hmm it makes sense for it to be a Stephen King's movie adaptation. I believe this is it. I saw the youtube trailer and David Morse is the pilot! I'm gonna have to rewatch it all 3 hours of it though. Thanks! I can't believe it!

Comment: Awesome special effects.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Indeed I was so wrong at that! haha!